# How can I modify the offset value after a Popper is created?

Tags: popper.js

Since my page layout changes at different responsive breakpoints, I need a way to change the offset of my Popper programmatically after it is created.  I see that I can create a custom Modifier, and potentially do it that way, but was curious if there is a simpler way, since the offset Modifier does everything i need, i just need to be able to change the value.